# Is having a GUID in a https url secure enough?

Tags: tls, web-application

Is having a GUID in a https url secure enough? Are there any security risks of using this way of authenticating users?

https://mywebsite.com/......?Guid=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Also what measures can be taken to make this kind of URLs more secure.

Comment: To a large degree, it depends on your threat model.  See the other question to review the potential issues with secret URLs.

Comment: Also see other questions and their answers [on the topic](http://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=guid+url)

Answer (score 5):

A session id should be a Cookie parameter,  and should never appear in the URL.  Any value in the URL A will show up in the referer header,  as well as access log files.   A web application will end up transmitting authentication credentials to other websites,  and storing them in plaintext on the filesystem.

Additionally, when you pass a session id in the URL, you open the door for [Session Fixation](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_fixation).